# How to properly replay blocks to generate trace data?

Tags: nodeos, mainnet, history, full-node

When attempting to query a specific block against the trace_api on an EOS node that has full chain data and I'm receiving a 404 error.

```
curl https://mynode.localhost/v1/trace_api/get_block --data '{"block_num":"2000"}'| jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   115  100    96  100    19    111     21 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   132
{
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Block trace missing",
  "error": {
    "code": 0,
    "name": "",
    "what": "",
    "details": []
  }
}
```

I'm able to retrieve trace data for more recently blocks, it's only block before a certain height that are missing.

I'm actively using this node for other applications, however I need to access the missing trace data for several blocks. What are my options to generate this trace data? Am I able to simply replay the blockchain from the existing blocks.log to generate this trace data? Is there maybe another method that would prevent the incurring of a downtime on my node?

Are there any third parties that provide snapshots of trace data?

Comment: I'm not aware of trace data snapshots, only snapshots that allow you to play from the state of the snapshot forward.  So I believe a full replay is your only option.  Best to ask here: https://t.me/joinchat/0uhWYfXVpPlkNTA1